# Login status lost after closing the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login system using FormsAuthentication that for some reason is logging me out when closing and opening the browser. Here is how I have setup my login code:

```
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;

                ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, tbUsername.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), true, string.Empty, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;

            //Add the cookie to the request
            Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

As you can see I have set the cookie to be persistent across sessions. Here is my web.config part:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms slidingExpiration="false" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" name="BOIGAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Admin/Settings.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

Also, SessionState is disabled on this particular application. Anyone know what is wrong?

Btw leaving the application browser on for more than 2 hours kept me logged in even though I did not interact with the website. The cookie is only being lost when closing the browser.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tested it both on Firefox and Chrome, I don't think it is a browser issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't set expiration on cookie it will be browser-session-only cookie and disappear after you close all instances of browser.

You need to set some expiration on your cookie for it to be persistent with [Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.expires%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property.

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
   FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1000);
```

Side note: make sure your browser is not configured to clear all cookies on close.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper, not sure what "Ticker" is... You need cookie itself to have expiration set, browser don't care about value of the cookie.

Comment: I meant Ticket, sorry. It has a value for expiration so I assumed it was cookie expiration. Will try to set it both on the cookie and on the Ticket.